# How to get the ID of Query

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `LastPosition` (
`Id` CHAR(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Serial` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`DateGps` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`Id`, `DateGps`),
KEY `serial_idx` USING BTREE (`Serial`),
KEY `dategps_idx` USING BTREE (`DateGps`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

And this query

```
SELECT
    Serial,
    MAX(DateGps) AS maxi
FROM
    LastPosition
GROUP BY
    Serial
ORDER BY 
    DateGps
```

How can I get the id of the record with the max of DateGPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you could get more than 1 row just in case there are two or more records with the same DateGps.

```
SELECT lp.Id
FROM   LastPosition lp
JOIN   (SELECT  Serial,
                MAX(DateGps) AS maxi
        FROM    LastPosition
        GROUP BY Serial) t1
ON      lp.Serial = t1.Serial
AND     lp.DateGps = t1.maxi;
```